# Как сформировать двумерный список слов в Питоне из списка строк?

Tags: python, list, строки

Представим, что дан некий одномерный список строк.

list_first = ['A man in man', 'Dog is an animal', 'I wasn't there yesterday']

Из него я хочу получить такой список списков:

list_second = [ ['a', 'man', 'in', 'man'], ['dog', 'is', 'an', 'animal'], ['i', 'wasn', 't', 'there', 'yesterday']

Что для этого надо сделать? Сколько не пытаюсь - проблемы с типами данных

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ. Добавьте код своей лучшей попытки.

Answer (score 0):

самое простое решение - в лоб:

```
list_first = ['A man in man', 'Dog is an animal', 'I wasn\'t there yesterday']

list_second = [text.split() for text in list_first ]
```

правда у такого способа есть недостаток - он режет только пробелы, а у вас еще и по `'` надо отрезать

Comment: Выскакивает такая ошибка: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: странно, у меня все работает, покажите свой код PLZ

Comment: file_obj = open('sentences.txt') # некоторый файл с предложениями
text1 = file_obj.read()
text2 = text1.lower()
text_for_5 = text2.split('\n')
text_for_5.remove('')
list_second = [text.split() for text in text_for_5]

Comment: и что находится в `text_for_5`?

Comment: Список строк-предложений. Специально пробил еще и тип text_for_5. class 'list', все нормально с типом

Comment: @Zhihar Очень похоже на задачу с "кодварс"... там бывает методы стандартные "отключают" в тестах и в условиях об этом пишут...

Comment: а... ну тогда хорошо бы об этом сказать заранее :)

Comment: Такс. Каким-то образом мой text_for_5 стал двумерным списком. Стоит отметить, что я работу делаю в Jupiter Notebook. Видать, в прошлых попытках мой одномерный список как-то успел измениться, несмотря на ошибки. Тогда я пытался все записать в новый список. Странно, но теперь понятно, почему Ваш метод не сработал) А так, спасибо, за помощь!